# Xcode 6.1.1 (null) cannot run arm64

Tags: ios, build, xcode6.1, arm64

I'm running app on iPad 3 mini device. All of sudden I'm getting (`null) cannot run arm64 message` and build fails. I'm using OS X 10.10.1 and Xcode 6.1.1. Why this message?

[image: Screenshot for warning]

Comment: check your Build Settings to targets of your project is support for arm64?

Comment: I've seen several "unexplainable" events when building OS X and iOS apps with the latest Xcode. Have you tried rebooting? I know that sounds like a illogical answer, but it solved one of the strange things I saw on my machine after leaving it running for a week.

Comment: in my case, just tried to re-run, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

I was using a non-apple cord and it somehow disconnected in between starting the build and running, so the device changed from my iOS device to a "Generic iOS Device".

Try reconnecting the device or a new cable and running again.